# selenium action chains no effect

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using selenium on python and want to open a new tab in chrome.
I tried

```
  ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('t').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
```

but that makes no effect. nothing happened.
I've also tried

```
send_keys(Keys.CONTROL+'t')
```

but that also makes no effect.
How can I open a new tab in selenium?

Comment: simular question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17325629/how-to-open-a-new-window-on-a-browser-using-selenium-for-python

Comment: Do you want to open  empty new window??

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to open a new tab the following way:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://www.google.com')

q = browser.find_element_by_name('q')
q.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 't')

browser.close()
```

Chrome 44.0.2403.89 (64-bit), Selenium 2.46.1 on Ubuntu 12.04.

Notice that I am using `,` and not a `+` in the `send_keys()` function.

Answer (score 0):

```
ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys(str('\u0074')).perform()
```

\u0074 represents the character 't'

To press other characters refer the unicode character table - http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0000.pdf

Answer (score 0):

> For performing such automation operations you might wanna use something that's built over selenium to handle all such tasks like tab switching , automatic element finding , Special Key press and hold  :etc.

Take a look at : "webbot"

webbot works even for webpages with dynamically changing id and classnames and has more methods and features than selenium and mechanize.

Here's a small snippet

```
from webbot import Browser 
web = Browser()
web.go_to('google.com') 
web.click('Sign in')
web.type('mymail@gmail.com' , into='Email')
web.click('NEXT' , tag='span')
web.type('mypassword' , into='Password' , id='passwordFieldId') # specific selection
web.click('NEXT' , tag='span') # you are logged in ^_^
```

For your specific usage :

```
web.press( web.Key.CONTROL + 't' )
```