# Python, selenium, Chrome and ActionChains to save a webpage

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to have Python, Chrome and ActionChains to save a webpage.

The code seemed like ever works fine on an computer but not another.

I checked the code and also tried the suggestions gave at [selenium action chains no effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31556122/selenium-action-chains-no-effect), but it still doesn't work.

Where went wrong? thanks.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import win32com.client as comclt

chromedriver = "c:\Python27\\chromedriver.exe"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.maximize_window()

aaa = driver.get("https://sg.yahoo.com/?p=us")
time.sleep(3)

save_me = ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).key_down('s').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).key_up('s')
save_me.perform()
time.sleep(2)
wsh= comclt.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
wsh.AppActivate("chrome")
time.sleep(1)
wsh.SendKeys("{ENTER}")

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems like the versions for Chrome and Chromedriver (32-bit, 64-bit) matter. Tried another version it may work fine.