# How to scrape information from tables selecting each of the Dropdown options using Selenium and Python?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, html-select, webdriverwait

Trying to help someone who works for a nonprofit. Currently trying to pull info from the STL County Boards/Commissions website(https://boards.stlouisco.com/).

Having trouble for a few reasons:

Was going to attempt to use BeautifulSoup, but the actual data isn't even shown until you choose a Board/Commission from a dropdown bar above, so I have switched to Selenium, which I am new at.

Is this task possible? When I look at the html code for the site, I see that the info isn't stored in the page, but pulled from another location and just displayed on the site based on the option chosen from the dropdown menu.

```
function ShowMemberList(selectedBoard) {
        ClearMeetingsAndMembers();
        var htmlString = "";
        var boardsList = [{"id":407,"name":"Aging Ahead","isActive":true,"description":"... ...1.","totalSeats":14}];
        var totalMembers = boardsList[$("select[name='BoardsList'] option:selected").index() - 1].totalSeats;
        $.get("/api/boards/" + selectedBoard + "/members", function (data) {
            if (data.length > 0) {
                htmlString += "<table id=\"MemberTable\" class=\"table table-hover\">";
                htmlString += "<thead><th>Member Name</th><th>Title</th><th>Position</th><th>Expiration Date</th></thead><tbody>";
                for (var i = 0; i < totalMembers; i++) {
                    if (i < data.length) {
                        htmlString += "<tr><td>" + FormatString(data[i].firstName) + " " + FormatString(data[i].lastName) + "</td><td>" + FormatString(data[i].title) + "</td><td>" + FormatString(data[i].position) + "</td><td>" + FormatString(data[i].expirationDate) + "</td></tr>";
                    } else {
                        htmlString += "<tr><td colspan=\"4\">---Vacant Seat---</td></tr>" 
                    }
                }
                htmlString += "</tbody></table>";
            } else {
                htmlString = "<span id=\"MemberTable\">There was no data found for this board.</span>";
            }
            $("#Results").append(htmlString);
        });
    }
```

So far, I have this (not a lot), which goes to the page and selects every board from the list:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://boards.stlouisco.com/")
select = Select(wait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'BoardsList'))))
options = select.options

for board in options:
    select.select_by_visible_text(board.text)
```

From here I would like to be able to scrape the info from the MemberTable but I don't know how to move forward/if it is something in the scope of my abilities, or even if it is something possible with Selenium.

I've tried using find_by a few different elements to click on the members table but am met with errors. I have also tried calling for the memberstable after my select, but it is not able to find that element. Any tips/pointers/advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

To choose each of the *Board* / *Commission* from the [html-select](/questions/tagged/html-select) Dropdown and scrape the page you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://boards.stlouisco.com/")
select = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'BoardsList'))))
for option in select.options:
    option.click()
    print("Scrapping :"+option.text)
```

Console Output:

```
Scrapping :---Choose a Board---
Scrapping :Aging Ahead
Scrapping :Aging Ahead Advisory Council
Scrapping :Air Pollution & Noise Control Appeal Board
Scrapping :Animal Care & Control Advisory Board
Scrapping :Bi-State Development Agency (Metro)
Scrapping :Board Of Examiners For Mechanical Licensing
Scrapping :Board of Freeholders
Scrapping :Boundary Commission
Scrapping :Building Code Review Committee
Scrapping :Building Commission & Board Of Building Appeals
Scrapping :Business Advisory Council
Scrapping :Center for Educational Media
Scrapping :Civil Service Commission
Scrapping :Commission On Disabilities
Scrapping :County Health Advisory Board
Scrapping :Domestic And Family Violence Council
Scrapping :East-West Gateway Council of Governments Board of Directors
Scrapping :Economic Development Collaborative Advisory Board
Scrapping :Economic Rescue Team
Scrapping :Electrical Code Review Committee
Scrapping :Electrical Examiners, Board Of
Scrapping :Emergency Communications System Commission
Scrapping :Equalization, Board Of
Scrapping :Fire Standards Commission
Scrapping :Friends of the Kathy J. Weinman Shelter for Battered Women, Inc.
Scrapping :Fund Investment Advisory Committee
Scrapping :Historic Building Commission
Scrapping :Housing Authority
Scrapping :Housing Resources Commission
Scrapping :Human Relations Commission
Scrapping :Industrial Development Authority Board
Scrapping :Justice Services Advisory Board
Scrapping :Lambert Airport Eastern Perimeter Joint Development Commission
Scrapping :Land Clearance For Redevelopment Authority
Scrapping :Lemay Community Improvement District
Scrapping :Library Board
Scrapping :Local Emergency Planning Committee
Scrapping :Mechanical Code Review Committee
Scrapping :Metropolitan Park And Recreation District Board Of Directors (Great Rivers Greenway)
Scrapping :Metropolitan St. Louis Sewer District
Scrapping :Metropolitan Taxicab Commission
Scrapping :Metropolitan Zoological Park and Museum District Board
Scrapping :Municipal Court Judges
Scrapping :Older Adult Commission
Scrapping :Parks And Recreation Advisory Board
Scrapping :Planning Commission
Scrapping :Plumbing Code Review Committee
Scrapping :Plumbing Examiners, Board Of
Scrapping :Police Commissioners, Board Of
Scrapping :Port Authority Board Of Commissioners
Scrapping :Private Security Advisory Committee
Scrapping :Productive Living Board
Scrapping :Public Transportation Commission of St. Louis County
Scrapping :Regional Arts Commission
Scrapping :Regional Convention & Sports Complex Authority
Scrapping :Regional Convention & Visitors Commission
Scrapping :REJIS Commission
Scrapping :Restaurant Commission
Scrapping :Retirement Board Of Trustees
Scrapping :St. Louis Airport Commission
Scrapping :St. Louis County Children's Service Fund Board
Scrapping :St. Louis County Clean Energy Development Board (PACE)
Scrapping :St. Louis County Workforce Development Board
Scrapping :St. Louis Economic Development Partnership
Scrapping :St. Louis Regional Health Commission
Scrapping :St. Louis-Jefferson Solid Waste Management District
Scrapping :Tax Increment Financing Commission of St. Louis County
Scrapping :Transportation Board
Scrapping :Waste Management Commission
Scrapping :World Trade Center - St. Louis
Scrapping :Zoning Adjustment,  Board of
Scrapping :Zoo-Museum District - Art Museum Subdistrict Board of Commissioners
Scrapping :Zoo-Museum District - Botanical Garden Subdistrict Board of Commissioners
Scrapping :Zoo-Museum District - Missouri History Museum Subdistrict Board of Commissioners
Scrapping :Zoo-Museum District - St. Louis Science Center Subdistrict Board of Commissioners
Scrapping :Zoo-Museum District - Zoological Park Subdistrict Board of Commissioners
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Message: Element  could not be scrolled into view while trying to click on an option within a dropdown menu through Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51250668/message-element-option-could-not-be-scrolled-into-view-while-trying-to-click/51252175#51252175)
- [How to open the option items of a select tag (dropdown) in different tabs/windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51723000/how-to-open-the-option-items-of-a-select-tag-dropdown-in-different-tabs-window/51725219#51725219)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script to save all members from all boards to csv:

```
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://boards.stlouisco.com/'
members_url = 'https://boards.stlouisco.com/api/boards/{}/members'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

all_data = []
for o in soup.select('#BoardsList option[value]'):
    print(o['value'], o.text)
    data = requests.get(members_url.format(o['value'])).json()
    for d in data:
        all_data.append(dict(board=o.text, **d))

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
print(df)
df.to_csv('data.csv')
```

Prints:

```
                                                 board  boardMemberId  memberId boardName  ...   lastName                                  title                                           position expirationDate
0                                          Aging Ahead          39003     27007      None  ...   Anderson                                   None               ST. LOUIS COUNTY EXECUTIVE APPOINTEE      10/1/2020
1                                          Aging Ahead          38963     27797      None  ...     Bauers                                   None  St. Charles County Community Action Agency App...           None
2                                          Aging Ahead          39004     27815      None  ...  Berkowitz                                   None               ST. LOUIS COUNTY EXECUTIVE APPOINTEE      10/1/2020
3                                          Aging Ahead          38964     27798      None  ...     Biehle                                   None  Jefferson County Community Action Corp. Appointee           None
4                                          Aging Ahead          38581     27597      None  ...     Bowers                                   None               Franklin County Commission Appointee           None
..                                                 ...            ...       ...       ...  ...        ...                                    ...                                                ...            ...
725  Zoo-Museum District - Zoological Park Subdistr...          38863     26745      None  ...       Seat               (Robert R. Hermann, Jr.)                                   St. Louis County     12/31/2019
726  Zoo-Museum District - Zoological Park Subdistr...          38864     26745      None  ...       Seat                        (Winthrop Reed)                                   St. Louis County     12/31/2016
727  Zoo-Museum District - Zoological Park Subdistr...          38669     26745      None  ...       Seat                      (Lawrence Thomas)                                   St. Louis County     12/31/2018
728  Zoo-Museum District - Zoological Park Subdistr...          38670     26745      None  ...       Seat  (Peggy Ritter ) Advisory Commissioner                        Non-Voting St. Louis County     12/31/2019
729  Zoo-Museum District - Zoological Park Subdistr...          38394     27512      None  ...     Wilson                  Advisory Commissioner                       Non-Voting City of St. Louis           None

[730 rows x 9 columns]
```

And saves `data.csv` with all boards/members (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]