# How to select dropdown on Selenium using Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu, html-select, webdriverwait

I'm trying to select country but somehow it's not working. The code below is what I did. It's not working properly.

```
<select name="state" class="form-control selectpicker">
                                        <option value=" ">Please select your state</option>
                                        <option>Alabama</option>
                                        <option>Alaska</option>
                                        <option>Arizona</option>
                                        <option>Arkansas</option>
                                        <option>California</option>
                                        <option>Colorado</option>
                                     </select>
```

Here what I did: `browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".form-control.selectpicker [option='Alaska']").click()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select the `<option>` with text as **Alaska** you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  dropdown_menu = Select(browser.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@class='form-control selectpicker' and @name='state']"))
  dropdown_menu.select_by_visible_text('Alaska')
  ```

Ideally, you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use the following *Locator Strategy*:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and in a single line:

  ```
  Select(WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "select.form-control.selectpicker[name='state']")))).select_by_visible_text('Alaska')
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Message: Element  could not be scrolled into view while trying to click on an option within a dropdown menu through Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51250668/message-element-option-could-not-be-scrolled-into-view-while-trying-to-click/51252175#51252175)
- [How to open the option items of a select tag (dropdown) in different tabs/windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51723000/how-to-open-the-option-items-of-a-select-tag-dropdown-in-different-tabs-window/51725219#51725219)