# Is using the Select element instead of physically doing 'element.click()' bad practice in Test Automation?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu, webdriver, html-select

Is using the Select element instead of physically doing 'element.click()' bad practice in Test Automation?

I am concerned if we should even be using `<select>` elements since we are essentially bypassing the UI? Struggling to find discussions relating to this.

Answer (score 0):

[html-select](/questions/tagged/html-select) nodes must be always handled through [`Select(webelement)`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.select.html#selenium.webdriver.support.select.Select) class inducing [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()`. As an example:

- Using *Java*, *cssSelector* and `selectByVisibleText()`:

  ```
  new Select(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("selectElementCss")))).selectByVisibleText("visibleText");
  ```
- Using *Python*, *xpath* and `select_by_value()`:

  ```
  Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "select_element_xpath")))).select_by_value("option_value")
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of detailed discussions in:

- [How to open the option items of a select tag (dropdown) in different tabs/windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51723000/how-to-open-the-option-items-of-a-select-tag-dropdown-in-different-tabs-window/51725219#51725219)
- [How to select an option from a dropdown through Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49772710/how-to-select-an-option-from-a-dropdown-through-selenium-webdriver/49777340#49777340)
- [How to select a drop-down menu value with Selenium using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867537/how-to-select-a-drop-down-menu-value-with-selenium-using-python/62735660#62735660)
- [Message: Element  could not be scrolled into view while trying to click on an option within a dropdown menu through Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51250668/message-element-option-could-not-be-scrolled-into-view-while-trying-to-click/51252175#51252175)

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified. Iv never seen a select element on its own in the wild, it always has labels that can expand the dropdown list and <li> tags for the items in the list. This feels like a better approach as I am actually testing the UI interactions, instead of interacting with it programmatically (which I think SelectElement.selectByValue("test") does).