# Dynamically generate driver objects to manipulate windows using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Using the top answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17325629/how-to-open-a-new-window-on-a-browser-using-selenium-webdriver-for-python)  question to create new driver objects for each window using selenium (i.e. create a new variable name for a new webdriver object for each window). How can I name the new variable after a dictionary value through indexing a dictionary?

Here's a list of dictionaries:

```
individual_window_array = [{"window_numeric_name/driver_object_name":f'{window_numeric_name}'}, {"window_description":f'{current_window_description}'}
                                       ,{"window_tabs":f'{current_window_tabs}'}, {"window_custom_title":f'{current_window_title}'}]
```

How do I dynamically name the new driver objects (corresponding to each window) after a value of a dictionary indexed like this:

```
    new_window = next(iter(individual_window_array[0].values()))
```

Comment: I think the browsers already have this built-in.  (restore your last browsing session? prompt)  Selenium seems like the wrong tool for this job.  A browser extension/plugin might be more practical.

Comment: @pcalkins What I am trying to do is much more detailed than what the browser offers. Browsers don't offer the possibility to write a description or give sessions titles. This is also part of an overarching project and the data will be later used for more functionality. I know selenium wasn't built for this but I am experimenting with it. I think the problem now is more a python problem rather than a selenium problem as I have already found a way to retrieve all the info I need from selenium.